# d3 zoomable treemap - adding new captions in the right place

Tags: text, svg, d3.js, zooming, treemap

(d3 sure generating lots of questions)

I am trying to modify Mike's zoomable treemap (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/treemap/) so that the  value field is displayed in the centre of each 'parent' rect. Here's my new code which works fine... until I zoom in:

**CSS**

```
.overlaidText   {
    font-size: 2.2em;
    text-anchor: middle;
    fill: white;
    fill-opacity: 0.8;
    stroke: black;
    stroke-width: 1px;
    stroke-opacity: 0.5;
}
```

**JS**

```
    g.append("text")
      .classed("overlaidText",true)
      .text(function(d) { return Math.round(d.value)+"M"})
      .call(middletext);

    function middletext(text) {
      text.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.x + d.dx / 2); })
          .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.y + d.dy / 2) + 16; });
    }
```

Here is the live (broken) code: http://democra.me/treemap.htm

Does anyone know what I need to change to get the overlaidText nodes to behave when zooming (in and out)?

Comment: Are you also applying the text centering inside the onclick event listener (i.e. the `transition` function)?

Comment: I believe I am as the lines (265-269) grab all text nodes in g1 (the parent group):

t1.selectAll("text").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 0);

etc.

Comment: It may be worth generating a fiddle...makes it easier for others to spot the problem and help.

Comment: Thanks @FernOfTheAndes. I can't figure out how to get JSFiddle.net to use my JSON file. Their documentation is poorly written. Can you help with that? The rest of the code is loaded at http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6vN/3/.

Comment: Sure, check how I use the JSON variable in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/63Edr/) that I put together when answering another question on treemaps.

Comment: Thanks @FernOfTheAndes. I see you've just pasted the JSON into the Javascript. I have done the same (after simplifying it and shrinking the SVG to 360 x 300). It now works correctly in JSFiddle and I hope you can assist with the original question. See http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6vN/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6vN/9/) with the changes below. Is this what you are looking for?

```
// Transition to the new view.
t1.selectAll("text").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 0);
t2.selectAll("text").call(text).style("fill-opacity", 1);
t2.selectAll(".overlaidText").call(middletext).style("fill-opacity", 1); // added
t1.selectAll("rect").call(rect);
t2.selectAll("rect").call(rect);
```

Comment: Absolutely! Great stuff, thanks @FernOfTheAndes. I still need to fiddle a bit more but now on the right track.